# How to overlap element with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want element `ipsum` with text "Hello World" to overlap element `lorem` with text "This element should hidden behind"

Actually I can fix the issue by adding `background-color: white` into `ipsum` element. But in my case, I don't want to do that.

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.lorem {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.ipsum {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY(100px);
  /* Set a background color will work as expected. But I don't want to use background color because I believe forcing the background color to white or one color it's not good for the future */
  /* background: white; */
}
```

```html
<div class="container lorem">
  This should element should hidden behind
</div>
<div class="container ipsum">
  <br /> Hello world
</div>
```

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Actual:

[image: Actual]

Expected:

[image: Expected]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put your html and css in the question, rather than just linking to it. Ideally as a runnable snippet but, as a minimum, an [mcve] code block. Also, as noted, the element you wish to hide is already behind the other element but you don’t want to use a background colour to obscure its presence. What are you trying to achieve, since your ‘expected result’ would be easily achieved by styling the ipsum element’s background colour?

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica I don't want to use background color because I believe forcing the background color to white or one color it's not good for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed my issue.
By wrap the element of `container` into `app` element and add this style

```
.app {
  background-color: white;
}
.ipsum {
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

Now my component will overlap the `lorem` component but I can change the background color from the root (not forced to use one color)

```css
.app {
  background-color: white;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.lorem {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.ipsum {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY(100px);
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="container lorem">
    This should element should hidden behind
  </div>
  <div class="container ipsum">
    <br /> Hello world
  </div>
</div>
```